# Spark Core (1.5.2) and Scala.collection.mutable.Map

Tags: apache-spark

In my spark driver program, whenever I use the scala.collection.mutable.Map, I end up with

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:    scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;

For example, a call `Map[String,String]("x" -> "10", "y" -> "11")` generates the above error. The error goes away (and the program runs in Spark) if I take the Map object out.